# Better way to center text below overline with given length

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes

I need to create lines for signatures. I need 3 of them with different texts below them, but i want all lines to have the same length and the texts centered below them.
Tables with `\hline`s made the horizontal placement easy, but then the vertical placement of the lines was not as good as with `\overline`.

The following code achieves centering the text under the (over-)line with length of `xDatum/Unterschrift Ausbildungsleiterx`, but the question is: is there a better way to do it, because this feels like a very 'odd' solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\strich}[1]{%
  \makebox[\width][c]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \makebox[\widthof{xDatum/Unterschrift\ Ausbildungsleiterx}]{%
        #1%
      }%
    }%
    \makebox{%
      \ensuremath{%
        \overline{%
          \phantom{%
            \mathrm{xDatum/Unterschrift\ Ausbildungsleiterx}%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \footnotesize{\strich{Datum/Unterschrift\ Auszubildender}}
    \vspace{2.5cm}\\
    \footnotesize{\strich{Datum/Unterschrift\ Betreuer}\hfill\strich{Datum/Unterschrift\ Ausbildungsleiter}}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Notice, that `Datum/Unterschrift Ausbildungsleiter` is the longest of the 3 texts i need to place under the signature-lines.

Comment: you are missing an awful lot of `%` from the ends of your lines (which is why the lines are longer on the right than the left of your texts)

Comment: You are right. That happens, when you test your code and then start indenting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a `\parbox` and insert a `\rule`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

%Specify the longest signaturekey here:
\newcommand{\sigwidth}{\widthof{\footnotesize xDatum/Unterschrift\ Ausbildungsleiterx}}
%Define a signaturbox of 2.5 cm in height with a mandatory argument of the signature
\newcommand{\signaturehere}[1]{%
\parbox[b][2.5cm][b]{\sigwidth}{%
\footnotesize%Everything in footnotesize
\centering% 
\rule[-3pt]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}\\[0ex]%
{#1}%
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\signaturehere{Datum/Unterschrift\ Auszubildender}\\
\signaturehere{Datum/Unterschrift\ Betreuer}\hfill%
\signaturehere{Datum/Unterschrift\ Ausbildungsleiter}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is more or less what I just posted but you were first so +1, I deleted mine.

Comment: @David Yeah, just saw yours, it was a little more elegant though. But I guess multiple answers are often generated like that. (I will update my post in a second to make it more universal)

Comment: Thanks for that solution. Only one thing to point out for future readers: This breaks, if the current font size is bigger, so add a `\normalsize` in front of the signature lines.

Comment: This is unfortunately correct. I am going to fix that now, like in egreg's answer below the key is to set `\footnotesize` first.

Answer (score 6):

You can also automatize the computation of the largest text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\signaturelength}
\newcommand{\signatures}[3]{%
  \begin{center}\footnotesize % all is \footnotesize
  % compute the maximum width
  \setlength{\signaturelength}{\maxof{\widthof{#1}}{\widthof{#2}}}%
  \setlength{\signaturelength}{\maxof{\signaturelength}{\widthof{#3}}}%
  \addtolength{\signaturelength}{2em}% Add some space
  % print the three lines with their caption
  \strich{#1}\\[2.5cm]
  \strich{#2}\hfill
  \strich{#3}
  \end{center}
}

\newcommand{\strich}[1]{% The line and its caption
  \parbox[t]{\signaturelength}{\footnotesize % \parbox does \normalsize
    \centering\hrule\vspace{.5ex}\strut#1}}

\begin{document}

\signatures{Datum/Unterschrift Ausbildungsleiter}
  {Datum/Unterschrift Betreuer}
  {Datum/Unterschrift Ausbildungsleiter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Thanks to Heiko for spotting the misalignment of the rules.

Comment: `\parbox[t]` aligns the rules.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek You're right. I'll also add a strut.